# OS Command Injection and Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, security, veracode

A Veracode analysis of one of our assemblies finds that use of `System.Windows.AssemblyPart.Load(Stream)` is a "severe" security flaw because it allows for an OS command injection, or [CWE-78](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html).

We use AssemblyPart.Load when dynamically loading XAP modules: reading the AppManifest from the resource stream, parsing out the AssemblyParts, and then loading them.

First, it's not clear to me why the Load(stream) is a security flaw, as I can't find anything describing this flaw as it relates to Silverlight.

If it is potentially dangerous to the OS, how can it be mitigated?

Comment: We have the same question and whitelisting the assemblies before load didn't change the scan results.